# Extended DataGridView does not apply changes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I extended a `DataGridView` but unfortunately, after using a template from Toolbox, it generates default parameters for me. It looks like it overrides my settings. What im doing wrong here?

```
class CustomDataGrid2 : DataGridView
{
    public CustomDataGrid2() : base()
    {
        base.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
        base.ColumnHeadersHeight = 23;
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        base.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
        base.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        base.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;

        base.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        base.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 186);
        base.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        base.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 150);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
// 
// customDataGrid21
// 
this.customDataGrid21.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
this.customDataGrid21.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.customDataGrid21.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
this.customDataGrid21.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.customDataGrid21.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
this.customDataGrid21.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 138);
this.customDataGrid21.Name = "customDataGrid1";
this.customDataGrid21.RowHeadersVisible = false;
this.customDataGrid21.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 150);
this.customDataGrid21.TabIndex = 3;
```

As you can see I set `DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing` but it generated `AutoSize`

I also tried:

```
class CustomDataGrid4 : DataGridView
{
    public CustomDataGrid4() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLayout(e);

        base.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
        base.ColumnHeadersHeight = 23;

    }
}
```

Result:

```
// 
// customDataGrid41
// 
this.customDataGrid41.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.customDataGrid41.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(96, 152);
this.customDataGrid41.Name = "customDataGrid41";
this.customDataGrid41.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
this.customDataGrid41.TabIndex = 3;
```

Solution:

```
class CustomDataGrid6 : DataGridView
{
    private DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode m_ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
    private int m_columnHeadersHeight = 23;

    public new DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode
    {
        get => this.m_ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode;
        set
        {
            this.m_ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = value;
            base.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = this.m_ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode;
        }
    }

    public int ColumnHeadersHeight
    {
        get => this.m_columnHeadersHeight;
        set
        {
            this.m_columnHeadersHeight = value;
            base.ColumnHeadersHeight = this.m_columnHeadersHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property in the overridden [OnLayout()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onlayout?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

> `MSDN`: Derived classes should override this method to do any custom layout
>   logic.

```
private DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode m_ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;

public CustomDGV() { }

protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLayout(e);
    base.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing; 
}

public new DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode
{
    get => this.m_ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode;
    set {  this.m_ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = value;
           base.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = this.m_ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode;
    }
}
```

When you will drop the Custom Control on a Form, `DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing` will be the applied value for `ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode`

Try it with a `Label.AutoSize` property. `Autosize = false` will be set in the Designer only when set in the `OnLayout()` method.

Comment: check my edit, it tried like you said but nothing changed

Comment: @Aleksy Ruszała   Strange. Just tested. Different Frameworks? Try to force it overriding the Property, too. Test the updated code (rebuild the project when you change a custom control class).

Comment: No idea why it don`t want to set my gridview as i coded. Project has been cleaned, rebuilded, restarted, even new class been created and still same.

Comment: Have you tested it the property override (`new`, in this case)? Can you tell me what Famework version and Visual studio version are you using?

Comment: thanks, this new method fix it and works correctly now :)

Comment: can you tell me how to do it for  ` base.ColumnHeadersHeight = 23;`

Comment: Good to hear it that you made it :) Changing the `ColumnHeadersHeight` is tricky. You would need to change the Font size. There's another way. Try, in the designer, to set the `ColumnHeaderBorderStyle` to `Custom`. You'll get an error message. But after that, you can change the Height of the Header as you please. Try to implement it in code. If you can't, make another question :)

Comment: ok, i found this way :) Its like make custom getters and setters ;)

Comment: Finally with your help i sloved it :)